# Android App Restarting

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm fairly new to Android and have just released on App to Google Play.  I had thoroughly tested the App for Android 2.3 and Android 4.0.

I have received two emails from users in which when they come back to the App, the App restarts to the Main Activity and they have to re-login - which is a bad experience for them.  I detected none of this during my testing, when the App was resumed it came back to the same screen left off, no login necessary.  I did find out from one user they have 4.1.2 installed on their phone, which I'm not sure if something change versus 4.0.

Any thoughts on why the App may be starting from the Main Activity (Login) versus where the user left off?

In my code, I have the following listed, but do not call these:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Are you calling ``super.onStop()`` on ``onDestroy`` or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Not a copy/paste error.  Should that be changed to super.onDestroy()?  I didn't catch that before.

Comment: When you override a method, you call the corresponding method in the super class to make sure that the things that need to be done are actually done.  If you're calling super.onStop() even though you're overriding onDestroy() the things that super.onDestroy() need to do aren't going to happen, are they?